# How to get a single value without using group by Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have this data and i need to combine all lines in a row in field fullname and get a single value from 3 equals from order field. How can i do that without using a group by?

**Existing data**

```
id order fullname
1 32 Jack Stinky Potato
2 32 Kevin Enormous Cucumber
3 32 Jerald Sad Onion
```

**Expecting result**

```
32 Jack Stinky Potato, Kevin Enormous Cucumber, Jerald Sad Onion
```

using group by would write

```
select order, wm_concat(fullname) from EmployeeCards
group by order
```

or this, but it doesn't rational.

```
 select wm_concat(unique order), wm_concat(fullname) from EmployeeCards
```

or just  `select (unique order), wm_concat(fullname) from EmployeeCards`
don't working. Which aggregate function shoul i use to get a single value? Thanks

Comment: Certainly not `WM_CONCAT`, which was never documented, never supported, and has been deprecated for a very long time, and completely removed since Oracle 12.1 - you can't use it at all anymore since that version.

Comment: Find a better title to your post

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/dukeganote/oracle-sql-listagg-in-oracle-9i-021418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT
    "order",
    LISTAGG(fullname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS fullnames
FROM EmployeeCards
GROUP BY
    "order";
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Also, please avoid naming your database objects (e.g. tables, columns, etc.) using reserved SQL keywords, such as `ORDER`.

Comment: My db can't find the listagg function(

Comment: Then you must be using a _really_ outdated version of Oracle.  It is time to upgrade `:-)`